# Not an editor command: :Ex

Tags: vim, neovim

I would like to always open a vertical split with Explore whenever I open a file in vim. So I added the following list to my init.vim

```
topleft vsplit | :vertical resize 30 | :Ex
```

however I get the following error message.

```
Not an editor command:  :Ex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however I get the following error message.

So the command is invalid. `:Ex` is provided by a plugin (usually netrw). The message means that netrw is not loaded (yet).

> I added the following list to my init.vim

Please, take your time reading `:h startup`. To put it short, `vimrc` (or `init.vim`) is processed long before any plugin is loaded. You really should delay your command until `VimEnter` event. Kind of

```
if v:vim_did_enter
    DoSomethingIfSourcedManually
else
    autocmd VimEnter * ++once ++nested DoSomethingOnStartup
endif
```